# I can change background images, but how to print link?

Tags: javascript, background-image

I am using JavaScript to randomly change the background image upon refresh. What I have been wanting to do is then take the current `background-image` url and paste it in a certain div within

```
<a href=""></a>
```

so that people can download the image.

The background image script works and is as follows:

```
var totalCount = 3;
function ChangeIt() 
{
    var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
    document.body.background = 'bgimages/'+num+'.jpg';
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";// Background repeat
}
```

Sorry if this is easy but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it! Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have this link somewhere in your document and you want it to point to the current background image:

```
<a href='#' id='bgDownload'>Download background image</a>
```

The following function changes now the "href"-attribute of the link to the current background and the background itself:

```
var totalCount = 3;
function ChangeIt() 
{
    var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
    document.body.background = 'bgimages/'+num+'.jpg';
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";// Background repeat

    // change link
    document.getElementById("bgDownload").href = 'bgimages/'+num+'.jpg';
}
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks! A few awesome answers I was able to do exactly what I needed. I especially liked that you kept all the javascript in the head. Thanks alot atreju!

Answer (score 1):

Put a `DIV` on your page in the HTML, and switch the content using...

```
document.getElementById("[ID of DIV]").innerHTML = '<a href="' + [link_var] + '">' + [text_var] + '</a>';
```

Something like this...

```
document.getElementById("[ID of DIV]").innerHTML = '<a href="bgimages/' + num + '.jpg">Image #' + num + '</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<a href='javascript:window.location.href=document.body.background'>
   Download Background
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function downloadImage{ 
    window.open(document.body.background,'_blank'); 
   }
```